# Are content types in Drupal 8 the same as tables in a database?

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-8

If I am creating a database and I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship, I would create a third table to represent the relationship.

But how should I implement the above data model in Drupal 8, should I create three content types? so my question is, are content types in Drupal 8 the same as tables in a database, or are they something else that should be used in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

To store data in a custom table in Drupal 8 you're going to want to define a custom schema and expose it through a hook. Here is [Acquia's documentation](https://docs.acquia.com/tutorials/fast-track-drupal-8-coding/store-data-custom-table/) on that process. This is not the same as creating a content type.

Content type data is stored across several tables that are shared by other content types (such as `node` and `node_revision`) and manipulating these tables is not easy.

The quickest way to add a content type is through the method recommended in [Adding a Content Type](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/structure-content-type.html) from chapter 6 of the Drupal 8 User Guide. This allows for all the standard GUI methods for manipulating data structures.

Answer (score 0):

As Isaiah says, content types in Drupal are not technically the same as tables in a database as they use many tables. But!

In your case, if you have something like table A with:

```
- name
- email
- phone
- id
```

And a second table, table B with:

```
- company
- something else
- etc…
- id
```

and are looking at a third that would likely be something like:

```
- id
- table A id
- table B id
```

**Then the answer is yes**.

In this case you would have content type A with fields for name, email, phone, and then an entity reference field pointing to content type B with the company fields.

You can reference in any direction with the entity reference field.

You might also find "[Is there a way to input the data of multiple content types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398614/is-there-a-way-to-input-the-data-of-multiple-content-types-all-on-the-same-page/52421401#52421401)" helpful.