# Is there a way to input the data of multiple content types all on the same page in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have three content types: `student`, `course`, and `student_takes_course` (`student_takes_course` have two reference fields that points to the `student` and `course` content types).

To input a new `student_takes_course` record, I would first have to go to the `student` content type and input a new `student` record, and then go to the `course` content type and input a new `course` record, and only then I can go to the `student_takes_course` content type and input a new record that have references to the newly inputted `student` and `course` records).

But is there a way to input the `student` and `course` and `student_takes_course` records all on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

[Inline entity form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) allows you to create new, or reference existing, entities while creating/editing a parent.

This is a hugly powerful module, but can become confusing if you use it on both the parent and child, e.g. `student_takes_course` has an IEF referencing `student`, and `student` and a corresponding IEF referencing `student_takes_course`.

In this case you can create a new `student (2)` from `student_takes_course (1)` and then create a new `student_takes_course (3)` from `student (2)` and then a new s`student (4)` from `student_takes_course (3` and so on.

- student_takes_course
- - student
- - - student_takes_course
- - - - student

The way around this is to use form modes to limit the fields shown in each IEF. Or don't have corresponding reference fields…